# WPF DataGrid setting text wrap when IsSelected

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a WPF DataGrid row TextBlock's `TextWrapping` property to `Wrap` when that row is selected, using the same technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630805/1015498).

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            </Trigger>                        
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The background colour changes fine, but the wrapping property does not appear to be set.

I've also tried creating a `TextBlock` style, but then had other issues accessing the `IsSelected` property. I get the feeling there's a minor change I should be making here.

Edit: It also seems like I might be able to go down the route of styling each `DataGridTextColumn`, though I was looking for a more global option especially when columns may be automatically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've also tried creating a `TextBlock` style, but then had other issues accessing the IsSelected property.

This `ElementStyle` should work:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

If you are auto generating your columns, you could define the `ElementStyle` as a resource and handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    DataGridTextColumn column = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (column != null)
    {
        column.ElementStyle = dataGrid.Resources["ElementStyle"] as Style;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ElementStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to easily make this apply to all text columns? I might have automatically generated ones.

Comment: @Dan: Yes. Define the ElementStyle as a resource and handle the AutoGeneratingColumn event. Please let me know if you want me to provide an example.

Comment: That might be useful, yes. The aim of the original question was to avoid specifying on a column-by-column basis.